# Trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on Lenovo 330s ryzen 5 2500u

Tags: system-installation

Can boot from usb and get to try or install then screen goes black 5 min later nothing still black screen Ubuntu made with Rufus as uefi boot.

Comment: select try or install (depending what you want) and then hit f6 and at the end of the line add `nomodeset` and hit enter. this will disable some video driver stuff that might be causing your issue.

Comment: Thanks will try that. Should have said also had to disable fast boot and secure boot. Nothing seemed to help. Recently bought the laptop to remove win 10 run Ubuntu

Comment: Sorry I had a work emergency and couldn't try till today. Thanks, but not working am trying other ways to get this to work will post if I find a cure.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit late since this post is one month old, but if I can help other persons facing the same probleme...
I managed to boot ubuntu and fedora on this model (Lenovo ideapad 330s amd Ryzen 5 2500 u ) by:

1. Disabling secureboot of the UEFI BIOS (you will easily find how to do this on internet)
2. Disabling APIC support at the boot.
   In the grub menu just before boot, press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit boot options and then add `noapic` just after the word `vmlinuz`.

This should do the trick.

Comment: Does the touchpad work on your laptop? I had the very same problem, but my touchpad is not working at all.