# Does Ubuntu support AMD Ryzen APUs with Vega 8 Graphics?

Tags: boot, live-usb, gpu

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my new laptop. It is a Lenovo Ideapad 330s-15ARR with a Ryzen 2500U APU with Vega 8 Graphics, 12GB of RAM, and a 128GB M.2 NVMe boot  SSD. I have downloaded the most recent ISO of Ubuntu and flashed it onto my usb drive. Tested it on my main computer, where it works perfectly and I can boot into Ubuntu. However, on my laptop, I get to the boot screen where I select whether to install, or test without installing. And I have tried both (and with their safe options) and I just get a black screen after. Nothing happens. My BIOS is up to date. All that I'm left to assume is that it has something to do with support for Vega 8 Graphics on APUs. I tried the most recent Ubuntu LTS (18.04.3) and the most recent new version of Ubuntu (19.10). They both have the same issue. I have gotten Manjaro (KDE Plasma 18.1.5, XFCE 18.1.5 had strange random artifacting issues) installed and working perfectly. However I would like to install Ubuntu and use it instead. Is there anything I can do? I've heard some people have gotten Ubuntu working on the same APU and haven't even had the issues I have so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Check again for a BIOS update, and also check for any SSD firmware updates.  Any additional hardware, like Nvidia in the machine?  19.10 kernel should be good for your 2500U. A friend got a 2400U+Vega working with BIOS+5.0 kernel.

Comment: @ubfan1 Everything is as up to date as it can be. And there's no Nvidia hardware, it's using the Vega 8 integrated graphics on the 2500U. So I'm very unsure as to why it's happening.

Comment: See if acpi=0 on the grub linux boot line gets you running in a limited fashion (like with only 1 CPU).  If that works, try other acpi=xxx things which might not be as drastic.

Comment: I'm on mobile and on the way to an NYE party so I can't check right now but Google "2500U raven_dmcu.bin" see if you can get into recovery mode to delete this file in firmware folder

Comment: @Tek There is no recovery mode. The SSD in the system currently only has Manjaro installed. I have the Ubuntu ISO flashed onto a USB for install so there's no recovery mode for me to do anything like that. I saw similar things with the raven dmcu bin file before but I have a bigger issue it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another question from October that had the same issue that I had, and found that the answer did fix my problem. Secure Boot needed to be disabled (which I already had done). And APIC support needed to be disabled at the boot. I followed the intructions in the following post for that and got Ubuntu installer from my flash drive to boot up and was able to install it to my NVMe SSD. The trackpad didn't work on the live Ubuntu build while installing, but after installing it and allowing the installer to download all necessary drivers Ubuntu boots up perfectly and my trackpad works perfectly. 
See answer here:
[Trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on Lenovo 330s ryzen 5 2500u](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075796/trying-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-on-lenovo-330s-ryzen-5-2500u)